Rust panics with Os { code: 61, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }
Context
Hi. I’m quite new to Rust, and as I hope to gradually convert to being a fellow rustacean, I was ambitious (read: foolish) enough to retry a project (originally written in Go) I had last semester at uni, in Rust. The course project is about writing a real-time program controlling 3 elevators that communicate to serve ALL orders. The specifications are strict, so there is zero tolerance for lack of service — not even cosmic waves or network failures.
After beginning to read the official Rust book, it seemed too good to be true that the language was inspired by a suboptimal elevator, hence my desire to oxidize this previous project.
So far, I’m only at the point where I want to initialize drivers and crates that are handed to us by the course staff (ref. Hardware Driver and Network Driver).
The problem
Os { code: 61, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }

You can view the current state of my project on GitHub.

Note: As this is only the beginning of my implementation, the code is heavily influenced by other hand-ins. I claim no full ownership of the code as it is now, as I have only made minor modifications so far.

Some insight from someone more experiences in Rust would be appreciated. I have included the debug log from BACKTRACE=full below, as well as the most relevant code snippet.
Attempted solutions

I have already seen a lot of posts about the macOS firewall, hence I have attempted to disable it, but to no avail.
I have also tried to switch out localhost for 127.0.0.1, but this also doesn’t seem to solve the issue.

Device
I am currently developing on a Macbook Pro 2021 with:

CPU: Apple M1 Pro
Memory: 16GB
OS version: Seqouia 15.0.1

However, the program will eventually be run on Ubuntu 22
Minimal, Reproducible Example
Instructions:

Copy this code into your main.rs.
Run the project with cargo run.
The issue should reproduce, showing the “Connection Refused” error.

// src/main.rs

use crossbeam_channel as channel;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

// Simulating the config module
pub struct HardwareConfig {
    pub driver_address: String,
    pub driver_port: u16,
    pub num_floors: u8,
    pub driver_channel_poll_timeout_milliseconds: u64,
}

pub fn load() -> Config {
    Config {
        hardware: HardwareConfig {
            driver_address: "127.0.0.1".to_string(),
            driver_port: 15657,
            num_floors: 4,
            driver_channel_poll_timeout_milliseconds: 100,
        },
    }
}

pub struct Config {
    pub hardware: HardwareConfig,
}

// Simulating the elevator module
pub struct Elevator {
    socket: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>,
    pub num_floors: u8,
}

impl Elevator {
    pub fn init(addr: &str, num_floors: u8) -> Result<Elevator, std::io::Error> {
        Ok(Self {
            socket: Arc::new(Mutex::new(TcpStream::connect(addr)?)),
            num_floors,
        })
    }

    pub fn motor_direction(&self, _dirn: u8) {}
    pub fn call_button_light(&self, _floor: u8, _call: u8, _on: bool) {}
    pub fn floor_indicator(&self, _floor: u8) {}
    pub fn door_light(&self, _on: bool) {}
}

// Simulating the hardware module with ElevatorDriver
pub struct ElevatorDriver {
    elevator: Elevator,
    hw_motor_direction_rx: channel::Receiver<u8>,
    hw_button_light_rx: channel::Receiver<(u8, u8, bool)>,
    hw_request_tx: channel::Sender<(u8, u8)>,
    hw_floor_sensor_tx: channel::Sender<u8>,
    hw_floor_indicator_rx: channel::Receiver<u8>,
    hw_door_light_rx: channel::Receiver<bool>,
    hw_emergency_halt_tx: channel::Sender<bool>,
    hw_obstruction_tx: channel::Sender<bool>,
    terminate_rx: channel::Receiver<()>,
}

impl ElevatorDriver {
    pub fn new(
        config: &HardwareConfig,
        hw_motor_direction_rx: channel::Receiver<u8>,
        hw_button_light_rx: channel::Receiver<(u8, u8, bool)>,
        hw_request_tx: channel::Sender<(u8, u8)>,
        hw_floor_sensor_tx: channel::Sender<u8>,
        hw_floor_indicator_rx: channel::Receiver<u8>,
        hw_door_light_rx: channel::Receiver<bool>,
        hw_emergency_halt_tx: channel::Sender<bool>,
        hw_obstruction_tx: channel::Sender<bool>,
        terminate_rx: channel::Receiver<()>,
    ) -> Result<ElevatorDriver, std::io::Error> {
        let elev = Elevator::init(
            &format!("{}:{}", config.driver_address, config.driver_port)[..],
            config.num_floors,
        )?;
        Ok(ElevatorDriver {
            elevator: elev,
            hw_motor_direction_rx,
            hw_button_light_rx,
            hw_request_tx,
            hw_floor_sensor_tx,
            hw_floor_indicator_rx,
            hw_door_light_rx,
            hw_emergency_halt_tx,
            hw_obstruction_tx,
            terminate_rx,
        })
    }

    pub fn run(&self) {
        loop {
            // Just a mock implementation of the event loop
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    }
}

// Main function
fn main() {
    let config = load();

    let (_hw_terminate_tx, hw_terminate_rx) = channel::unbounded::<()>();
    let (_, hw_motor_direction_rx) = channel::unbounded::<u8>();
    let (_, hw_button_light_rx) = channel::unbounded::<(u8, u8, bool)>();
    let (hw_requests_tx, _) = channel::unbounded::<(u8, u8)>();
    let (hw_floor_sensor_tx, _) = channel::unbounded::<u8>();
    let (_, hw_floor_indicator_rx) = channel::unbounded::<u8>();
    let (_, hw_door_light_rx) = channel::unbounded::<bool>();
    let (hw_emergency_halt_tx, _) = channel::unbounded::<bool>();
    let (hw_obstruction_tx, _) = channel::unbounded::<bool>();

    let elevator_driver = ElevatorDriver::new(
        &config.hardware,
        hw_motor_direction_rx,
        hw_button_light_rx,
        hw_requests_tx,
        hw_floor_sensor_tx,
        hw_floor_indicator_rx,
        hw_door_light_rx,
        hw_emergency_halt_tx,
        hw_obstruction_tx,
        hw_terminate_rx,
    )
    .expect("Failed to initiate ElevatorDriver");

    let driver_thread = thread::Builder::new().name("driver".into());
    driver_thread
        .spawn(move || {
            elevator_driver.run();
        })
        .unwrap();

    loop {
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}


// config.toml

[hardware]
num_floors = 4
driver_address = "127.0.0.1"
driver_port = 15657
driver_channel_poll_timeout_milliseconds = 10

// Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "elevators"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ipeglin"]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
crossbeam-channel = "0.5.13"
driver-rust = { git = "https://github.com/TTK4145/driver-rust", tag = "v0.1.0" }
log = "0.4.22"
serde = { version = "1.0.204", features = ["derive"] }
toml = "0.8.14"


BACKTRACE
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=full cargo run
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/elevators`
thread 'driver' panicked at src/main.rs:40:18:
Failed to initiate ElevatorDriver: Os { code: 61, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x104ce640c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::hbebc8679d47bdc2c
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:116:5
   1:        0x104ce640c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h3a2e9637943241aa
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:        0x104ce640c - std::sys::backtrace::_print_fmt::he430849680584674
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:65:5
   3:        0x104ce640c - <std::sys::backtrace::BacktraceLock::print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h243268f17d714c7f
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:40:26
   4:        0x104cffa80 - core::fmt::rt::Argument::fmt::h0d339881c25f3c31
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/fmt/rt.rs:173:76
   5:        0x104cffa80 - core::fmt::write::hb3cfb8a30e72d7ff
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1182:21
   6:        0x104ce4394 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::hfb2314975de9ecf1
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1827:15
   7:        0x104ce74e8 - std::sys::backtrace::BacktraceLock::print::he14461129ccbfef5
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:43:9
   8:        0x104ce74e8 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h14c7718ccf39d316
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:269:22
   9:        0x104ce710c - std::panicking::default_hook::hc62e60da3be2f352
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:296:9
  10:        0x104ce7efc - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h09e8a656f11e82b2
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:800:13
  11:        0x104ce78fc - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h1230eb3cc91b241c
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:674:13
  12:        0x104ce6898 - std::sys::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hc3491307aceda2c2
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:168:18
  13:        0x104ce75c4 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:665:5
  14:        0x104d08190 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha4b80a05b9fff47a
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:74:14
  15:        0x104d084a0 - core::result::unwrap_failed::h441932a0bca0dd7f
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/result.rs:1679:5
  16:        0x104bd3224 - core::result::Result<T,E>::expect::h82c59d67b983c862
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/result.rs:1059:23
  17:        0x104bdc57c - elevators::main::{{closure}}::h33ca84fb51e125bc
                               at /Users/ipeglin/Git/elevators/src/main.rs:39:13
  18:        0x104bd7e48 - std::sys::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h7f356385b559c207
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:152:18
  19:        0x104be22f8 - std::thread::Builder::spawn_unchecked_::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::h5127590f39cf5314
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:538:17
  20:        0x104bfe0fc - <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once::h7b3ebab912333531
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:272:9
  21:        0x104bf3874 - std::panicking::try::do_call::he37a7015845ad2f0
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:557:40
  22:        0x104be2564 - ___rust_try
  23:        0x104be1ff4 - std::panicking::try::h0e50955f2944c437
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:521:19
  24:        0x104be1ff4 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h03ca9e17b8d56f53
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panic.rs:350:14
  25:        0x104be1ff4 - std::thread::Builder::spawn_unchecked_::{{closure}}::hc4ed7080e53500f9
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:537:30
  26:        0x104bf5ee0 - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h3c3b0d2607c5aa26
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  27:        0x104ce9c60 - <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::h01276ebbe54a8110
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:2070:9
  28:        0x104ce9c60 - <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::habad1faa89d23086
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:2070:9
  29:        0x104ce9c60 - std::sys::pal::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h1bd1b9c95010bf71
                               at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/sys/pal/unix/thread.rs:108:17
  30:        0x1818ef2e4 - __pthread_deallocate


Please add a minimal reproducible example Your snippets with the configuration omitted do not help. What service are you connecting to? It seems you just entered an invalid address or port as config.driver_address, config.driver_port is something even listening there?

Thanks for the helpful input. The address and port I'm trying to reach is simply my localhost or 127.0.0.1 on port 15657. I'd completely forgotten to include the config, but have now left them in as comments in the code. I'm working on making a minimal reproducible example as we speak.

So the problem is that the service on localhost:15657 did not accept the connection. What's running there, how did you start it.

You may need to enable Local Network Access for the binary in the system privacy settings.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
